# Discord.py - Sending message to specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My idea is to have logs

```py
channel = client.get_channel(732355984865099836)
await channel.send('Test')
```

Shouldn't this work to send a message to a specific channel? I searched the docs and some other answers but I have it exactly as in there.
It doesn't

I have couple more ctx.send('text')
but those are supposed to be sent on the channel the command is
and those do work if I put them on a line above than the one I just sent
if they are lower than it everything breaks

Comment: Try putting your channel ID in quotes. (aka making it a string)

Comment: It does need to be an int so dont put in quotes, and is there not any errors?

Comment: Can you please update your code to be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try this:
logs = ID_channel
await client.get_channel(logs).send(...)